# Deleting a record from a sqlite database when the user clicks alertview

Tags: ios, uitableview, sqlite, uialertview

I have a db table called `FINALORDER` which is populated with some data and is then displayed in a tableview.

I have inserted an `alertview` inside the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`..

```
    alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel Order" message:@"Do you want to cancel the order" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"dismiss" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
```

and the delegate method is as follows:

```
 - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
 {
const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
if(buttonIndex==1)
{
    NSString *deleteSQL = @"DELETE FROM FINALORDER WHERE itemname=?"; 

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [deleteSQL UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) 
        NSLog(@"%s error preparing %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database)); 
    if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [itemname UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) 
        NSLog(@"%s error binding %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database)); 
    if (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE) 
        NSLog(@"%s error executing %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database)); 
    if (sqlite3_finalize(statement) != SQLITE_OK) 
        NSLog(@"%s error finalizing %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));


}
 }
```

How am I supposed to get the item name which can be substituted in place of the question mark? Note that my database consists of the following fields `itemname,quantity,totalcost`

Comment: Why aren't you using CoreData with this? You know it's a SQLight database underneath. It's also a lot easier to use and you end up writing a lot less code to manage your data.

Comment: i am already cursing myself for it..lol..but i have come very far with my project looking back doesnt seem like an option..:-(

Comment: I would argue that it's always an option and it would make you life in the long run so much easier. At least you've defined the data model so implementing it in CoreData should be a breeze + there are plenty of examples out there for you to follow along with some good sample code available from Apple.

Comment: well i dont know much about core data..so i thought of not venturing in that plane..and i had limited time constraints..anyways i would definately give it a makeover once i finish this last part..i am this close to finishing,that is the reason i dont want to switch

Answer (score 1):

in didSelectRowAtIndexPath 
store the name in a class variable and then use it.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSArray *names = [cell.textLabel.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSString *temp;
for (int i=0; i<[names count]-2; i++) 
{
   if (!temp) 
   {
         temp = [names objectAtIndex:i];
   }
   else
   {
         temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",temp, [names objectAtIndex:i]];
   }
}
self.itemName = temp;
```

and use it

```
    NSString *deleteSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM FINALORDER WHERE itemname=%@",self.itemName];
```

hope it helps. happy coding :)

Comment: your answer seems correct but i dont have an arrayNameToDisplayData..i only have the records stored somewhere in the database..and i access them using a numericIds array..i hope you understood what i am saying

Comment: whatever way u are displaying the data, must be having an indexPath used for every cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath method. so in case of arrayNameToDisplayData u can directly access your database.

Comment: i have edited the answer according to ur needs, this should help u out

Comment: hey thanks..your answer seems very appropriate..but i still cant delete my element,your componentsSeperateByString returns only half of my element,e.g i have tomato soup..now it returns only tomato and therefore doesnt perform the deletion..anyways i would upvote your answer..thanks

Comment: i have modified it again, i didnt knw that u might have 2 words in item name, it has been added. change NSArray to NSMutableArray too. hope this one helps u finally :) and thanks for the upvote

Comment: what is t in    temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",t, [names objectAtIndex:i]]

Comment: its ok..but what change you suggested to me about NSArray to NSMutableArray,its giving me a warning,incompatible type

Comment: let it be NSArray, names datatype as NSArray. which line you are getting the warning?

Comment: remove NSMutableArray and write NSArray, it will remove that warning. made changes in the code

Comment: well i changed it to NSArray with no warnings now but my app just exits..i dont know why..:-(

Comment: can u tell me the crash log from the console?

Answer (score 1):

You could do what @AnshukGarg has suggested or as I would do it. You could create your own custom class that handles the UIAlertView.

For example:

```
         DataAlertThing.h

            #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

            @protocol DataAlertThingDelegate{
            @required

                -(void)shouldDeleteItem:(ItemType*)itemName;
            }

            @interface DataAlertThing : NSObject <UIAlertViewDelegate>
            @property (nonatomic, weak)id delegate;
            @property (nonatomic, strong) id itemName;

            -(id)initWithItemName:(ItemType*)myItemName;
        @end

    DataAlertThing.m

    #import "DataAlertThing.h"

    @implementation DataAlertThing



-(id)initWithItemName:(ItemType*)myItemName{
   self = [super init];
   if (self !=nil{
   self.itemName = myItemName;
  UIAlertView *alert = [UIalertVIew alloc]init...delegate:self..]
  [alert show];
}
 return self;
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
 {
if(buttonIndex==1)
{ 

   [delegate shouldDeleteItem:self.itemName];

 }
}
```

Hopefully from the above you get enough of an idea as to what I'm suggesting - you encapsulate your alert logic in your own custom class. You could also use a block at this point instead, but I think one example is enough for today :)

Please note this ARC and also using modern conventions so you don't need to right the @synthesize

In your existing code where you initialise the alert view. initialise this custom class instead.

```
whatever = [[DataAlertThing alloc]initWithItemName:myItemName];
[whatever setDelegate:self];
```

and implement the following

```
-(void)shouldDeleteItem:(ItemType*)itemName{
 //do what you need here to delete the record

}
```

Comment: i get your point..but could you suggest something other than this..i really dont know how you are going to pass your myItemName..NOTE:i have 3 fields in my db..i use a NSMutableArray called numericIds to display the data..i hope you understood what i mean..

Comment: then make "ItemType" id and then pass it an NSMutableArray after all it doesn't care what it's passing in or out as the DataAlertThing doesn't do anything with the data. Just keeps a pointer to it so it can tell the class that created it what to do.You then need to adopt the DataAlertThingDelegate protocol in your existing class (the class where you currently create the UIAlertView,so that it can respond to the call back and delete the record using the data passed to it.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the changes and to fix some fairly obvious omissions.

Comment: well how am i supposed to retreive the itemname in didSelect..coz i have used a NSMutableArray called numericIds to show the data in tableview format..you can have a look at it pastie.org/4630043

Comment: Can you not just use the recordId and then retrieve the item using that. Passing the recordId to your DataAlertThing and in the delegate call back retrieve the record that way

Comment: do you mean to say i pass the recordId and then retrieve the item and then delete query in the custom class??

Comment: You could do it in the custom class, but I would do it in the delegate call back.

Comment: well if that is the case..why should i create a custom class then? i could do everything in one class

Comment: I think I did suggest that, but this could be easily reused in other ways. Where you may also want to show and alert view and perform some action. Obviously you need to add a few more methods otherwise your likely to leak memory. But if I were you, I'd use @AnshukGarg answer as it is the simpler solution for you in this case :)

Comment: yeah i tried his solution but still i couldnt delete my element..but anyways thanks for the help..i am going to upvote you too..your idea was quite new to me..thanks